# duplicate domain name in address bar

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I using FormsAuthentication for my login.
and then I add this to a web.config.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Admin.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" 
timeout="1440" path="./" defaultUrl="AdminHome.aspx">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
              <user name="MyUser" password="MyPass"/>
            </credentials>
          </forms>
        </authentication>
```

when I running in server, I try to login.
and then the address bar become

http://mydomain.com/mydomain.com/default

whats the problem?

UPDATE
here's my code for login,

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(this.txtUsername.Text, this.txtPassword.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.txtUsername.Text, false);
           FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(this.txtUsername.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid login details. Please try again.");
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that runs when you "login"?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Admin.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" 
timeout="1440" defaultUrl="~/AdminHome.aspx">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
              <user name="MyUser" password="MyPass"/>
            </credentials>
          </forms>
        </authentication>
```